# Get field value in other language?

Tags: sitecore

How would i go about getting the value of a field in another language in Sitecore 6? To get the value of a field in the standard language i use the following `page.Fields["Title"].ToString()`.

How to accomblish this, if i want the value of the same field for English (en) for instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't get the value of the field for a different language without first getting the entire item in that language. In your case, `page` is in language 'x' and the `Title` field is in language 'x'. If you want the `Title` field in language 'y' you will need to get `page` in language 'y'.

```
Sitecore.Globalization.Language language = Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager.GetLanguage("en");
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item itemY = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/path/to/item", language);
string fieldY = itemY["Title"];
```